# Algorithm to find all fields of orders $p^n$ for fixed $n$ and all primes $p$ simultaneously?

Tags: algorithms, finite-fields

Is there an efficient way (an algorithm) to find, given a fixed $n\in\mathbb{N}_+$, all fields of order $p^n$ for all primes $p$ simultaneously?

There's no background behind this question, just an idea.

Given a prime $p$ and $n\in\mathbb{N}_+$ we can find a field of order $p^n$ using an irreducible polynomial $f$ of degree $n$ over $\mathbb{Z}_p[x]$ and considering the quotient $\mathbb{Z}_p[x]/(f)$. Can we achieve something like this but universally for all primes?

By that I mean, if we are able to find certain "thing" in finite time so that that thing will give us a description of all finite fields of order $p^n$ where $n$ is *fixed*.

Comment: I guess you should be a bit more specific about *for all primes simultaneously*. If the hope is that a clever choice of $f\in \Bbb{Z}[x]$ would work for all primes, then I'm afraid that is impossible. There are obstructions from algebraic number theory. Like Chebotarev's density theorem. I suspect (but won't bet on it) that the best possible choice of $f(x)$ would be one that has a cyclic Galois group of order $n$. Chebotarev says that this $f(x)$ remains irreducible for the fraction $\phi(n)/n$ of primes. Should $n$ be a prime itself, this is a relatively high percentage, but still $<1$.

Comment: Well, not necessarily an irreducible polynomial. But I don't know of any other possible description of a finite field. @AtticusStonestrom

Comment: Like $x^3-3x+1$ is irreducible modulo a prime $p\neq3$ unless $p\equiv\pm1\pmod9$.

Comment: @JyrkiLahtonen Thank you. I think that's the best answer I could ask for, really.

Comment: @JyrkiLahtonen no need for algebraic number theory; just consider any prime factor of any $n\in\operatorname{im}(f)\setminus\{\pm 1\}$ :)

Comment: @Jakobian as a side note, imo your question has an interesting subtlety with respect to "possible descriptions of a finite field"... in some sense, any finite field of order $p^n$ can be described as "the unique field of order $p^n$", and this characterizes it completely... but of course this isn't a satisfying answer, because that description is not very tractable for computations, etc. so I think there's an interesting question there as to what we consider a satisfactory "description" for the purposes of this question

Comment: if the question means expressing $\mathbb{F}_{p^n}$ as a quotient of $(\mathbb{Z}/p)[x]$ by an irreducible polynomial of degree $n$, then the answer to it is no, but perhaps there is a suitable weakening of the question that makes the answer yes while still retaining what we want in a tractable "description" of an algebraic object

Comment: Well, it doesn't have to be one polynomial. It can be a finite set of them depending on $n$, right.

Comment: @Jakobian ah, that's a very interesting variation on the problem!! I am fairly sure the answer is still no, but I can't think of a proof off the top of my head, and I suspect such a proof will require more advanced tools. however, I do have a proof for the case $n=2$. I've written both the general question and the proof up [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3944986/if-n1-are-there-f-1-dots-f-k-in-mathbbzx-of-degree-n-such-that-for), if you're interested

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I interpret your question as asking whether there is a polynomial $f\in\mathbb{Z}[x]$, of degree $n>1$, such that $\overline{f}$ is irreducible of degree $n$ in $(\mathbb{Z}/p)[x]$, for every prime $p$; unfortunately the answer to this is no. To see this, let $f\in\mathbb{Z}[x]$ be arbitrary. Find some $n\in\mathbb{Z}$ such that $\pm 1\neq f(n)=:m$, and let $p$ be any prime factor of $m$. Then $\overline n$ is a root of $\overline f$ in $(\mathbb{Z}/p)[x]$, since $\overline f(\overline n)=\overline m=\overline 0$, and thus $x-\overline n$ is a factor of $\overline f$, which is hence reducible (or of degree $\leqslant 1$) mod $p$.

Comment: Yeah. As they say in bridge circles to the players throwing curveballs to their unsuspecting partners, *KISS* (= Keep It Simple, Stupid). Chebotarev and friends are more of a tool for analyzing how often a given polynomial workds.

Comment: @JyrkiLahtonen that makes sense! :) probably a more satisfying answer for OP too, since it gives a best case